# to prevent Load multiple view in codeigniter and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is controller, if user login is failed then it load two view how to prevent

```
     public function index() {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('user/login');
        }

         public function success() {
                $data = array(
                    'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                    'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
                );
                $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
                if ($result == TRUE) {
                    echo 'Lgoin success';
                } else {
                    $data = array(
                        'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');

                    $this->load->view('user/login', $data);
                }
        }
```

send ajax form data to controller if user failed it show different view

```
<script>
    $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uname = $('#uname').val();
        var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
        if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
        {
            $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
        } else {
            $('#errmessage').html("").hide();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/success/",
                data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data);
                    setTime(function () {
                        $('#successmessage').fadeOut('slow');

                    }, 200);
                }
            });
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Not $this->load->view('user/login', $data); use redirect function

Comment: error message dose not display username n pass invalid

Comment: how to dispaly  message that is user name and password is worng

Comment: @user6171329 check my answer below....

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can be like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uname = $('#uname').val();
        var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
        if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
        {
            $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
        } else {
            $('#errmessage').html("").hide();
            $('#errmessage').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#successmessage').fadeOut('fast');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?=base_url("User_controller/success"); ?>",
                data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                dataType: 'jSon',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.status == true)
                    {
                        $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data.message);
                        setTime(function () {
                            $('#successmessage').fadeOut('slow');

                        }, 200);
                        $("#profile").html(data.html);//Add a div with id profile 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#errmessage').fadeIn().html(data.message);
                        setTime(function () {
                            $('#errmessage').fadeOut('slow');

                        }, 200);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Controller code can be

```
public function success()
{
    $data = array(
                'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
            );
   $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
   if ($result == TRUE) 
   {
       $html = $this->load->view("user/profile",$data,true);//THis will load profile view in a div you have to manage what to show
       $data = array('status'=>True,'message' => 'Login Successful','html'=>$html);
   } 
   else 
   {
       $data = array('status'=>False,'message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
   }
   echo json_encode($data);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: still same problem and i want load profile page,Not Login successfully message

Comment: It return only login success message but  i want load profile page

Comment: @user6171329 Ok for that you have to create a function in which you can load profile view. and use window.location to redirect. Updated according...

Comment: I have load view in if statement but  it show inside data only my login can't remove from main window

Comment: in controller i have if statement if reuslt is True then i want to load user profile view

Comment: i am new in ajax technology thanks in advance solve my prob

Comment: plz help me anyone

Comment: @user6171329 Updated thats all i can help if you found my answer useful dont forget to mark it... :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently codeigniter doesn't support the functionality you're looking for out of the box. I used the following work around.

First modify your function to something like this:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('user/login');
}
public function login_check(){
    //this function is for authentication

    $data = array(
        'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                  'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
    );
    $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);

    //if check is passed return back a json response containing the status
    if($result == TRUE){
        return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
        )));
    }

    //if check is failed return back a json response containing the status and error message
    else{
        return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'error_message' => 'invalid Username or Password'
        )));
    }
}
public function login_success(){
    //i'll assume that your profile view is called profile
    //this function is called once authentication is passed it is called as a consequence of the  triggered submit event of the form by jquery

    $this->load->view('user/profile', $data);
}
```

modify your form by setting the method="POST" and the action to 
"User_controller/login_success/". instead of using input tag of type button to submit the form, we will use a div with an id of submit. the onclick handler for our div will be used to post the data to login_check function of the User_controller via ajax. If the authentication is false we will receive an error message and bind it to the DOM if it is true then we will manually trigger the submit function of the login form via javascript which will call the login_success() function of the User_controller loading the profile view. 
the code is below:

```
<script>
//div#submit is our custom submit button

$('div#submit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var uname = $('#uname').val();
    var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
    if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
    {
        $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
    } else {
        $('#errmessage').html("").hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
         url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/success"); ?>",
         data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
         success: function (data) {
             if (data.success === false) {
                 //if authentication failed show error message
                 $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data.error_message);
                 setTime(function () {
                     $('#successmessage').fadeOut('slow');

                 }, 200);
             }
             //if authentication passed manually trigger form submission
             if (data.success === true) {
                 $('#login_form').trigger('submit');
             }

         }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```